# How to create 2 column form using bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created form using bootstrap 3. how can I make a 2 column form. that is the label on the left and the input, drop down  box etc on the right

```
          <fieldset>

                  <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputProject">Map info</label>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput" placeholder="">

                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Class</label>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTeam" placeholder="Team Project information">

                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputProject">  info</label>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput" placeholder="Build Defintion">

                  </div>

                  </fieldset>

                  <fieldset>

                  <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Name</label>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTeam" placeholder="Build Def Name">

                  </div>    



                  <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Location</label>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTeam" placeholder="Config Location">

                  </div>  

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding `<div class="col-md-6">` surrounding the two fieldsets

```
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <fieldset>
    ...
     </fielset>
  </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
       <fieldset>
    ...
      </fielset>
     </div>
 </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/JziKUuxQYM